# Weird TypeScript conditional types, is this a bug?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types, typescript-conditional-types

I am seeing discrepancies between individual versus nested condition types in TypeScript. The code below highlights the issue:

```js
type Equal<T, U> = T[] extends U[] ? U[] extends T[] ? true : false : false;
type IsAssignable<V, T> = T extends V ? true : false;
type IsFalse<T extends boolean> = IsAssignable<false[], T[]>;
type And<T extends boolean, U extends boolean> = IsFalse<T> extends true ? false : IsFalse<U> extends true ? false : T | U;

type TestType = string;
const test1: And<true, false> = false;
const test2: And<true, false> = true; // as expected: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2322)

const test3: Equal<TestType, number> = false;
const test4: Equal<TestType, number> = true; // as expected: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2322)

const test5: Equal<TestType, string> = false; // as expected: Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'true'.(2322)
const test6: Equal<TestType, string> = true;

// writing it out manually yields the expected result
const expected1: And<Equal<TestType, string>, Equal<TestType, number>> = false;
const expected2: And<Equal<TestType, string>, Equal<TestType, number>> = true; // as expected: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.(2322)

// but now the weird part, defining a shortcut
type shortcut<T> = And<Equal<T, string>, Equal<T, number>>;

// ...causes the returned result to be boolean (true | false) instead!
const weird1: shortcut<TestType> = false; // no compilation error!
const weird2: shortcut<TestType> = true; // no compilation error!
```

Can someone explain? Oh, and before someone points it out... I am aware that the definition of of `Equal` is different from the usual `[T] extends [U]` form, but this should work equivalently to my current understanding. If not, I'd be curious exactly why not. Thank you very much in advance!

Link: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsA8AVANFAqgPigF4oMBtAXSggA9gIA7AEwGc9KoB+dq2+5tuSrdgAJwTQAXFABmqFlNnyIAbgBQoSFACSLAIIsWASwDmDJACMUENADUcGQiQzU6jVlFtcoYiVGlyKArqmtC6AGLKmK78HhYA9vHWSAxOOvqGpuZWNoEKlA6U+CHg0HrM0XzubAlJECk4uDHVULXJqcTpkUE2js0CPuLQ3HmKEVEE-R6+w0o9-qRQAD546hqlpBAswBgbJNuiRgwm6gDG8QzbPlvAAIzS5UxoMzijaaNnF1f02wBMDxUXnMFGkZiooAB6CFQJBsWiQU70JjSXZaADkMzRUCMbAY8WAMMyZks1h88R8GzRozRADoABS-ADMv1+AEo1GpzpcCT9gIzpPBkOgMDdURAcAwEABbCwQUTvZSfbnXbYAFgFiFQmFFpQl0tl8s6YMh0NhrgRSJRlMx2Nx+MJxmJOTJFPR1PpTJZ7M5Xx5NwArBqhdrtmKcAcjiYFT1wVDCeaIIiIMjSJTqbaoHiCbDHdlScByaEoBihrSGcy2T7lbyAGxBrUi0O6qAR46goZrOMAd0OwEj2IJ8QQBKlKSFKBAUBARggKGmAAtoPDE0ioKItggUMAq1dl0mmPcoI80IKGzrIOGxJH8DhT8Lz+LM-q5fho8EdwS90j-keKneQzszatlGt6aveTYXk+Movu2EixqacI0BayZWuiNo4pm9o5lkJLQAWrrQFSyhlp6lZqHGFjDphXY+IuUBdhARiiEwUBgEgojADgTAQDIRz9kgLbzvEHGnMO6xaCwQkicOmBpMe-7YC2V5tqBwaKZK0HysUHJxjSemnEgCAKGwwB0euwAIKIDDJmuG5bi6sqtIk7RQHSMzLMCECsti3L1EwACEH70YxzGHpJwnAKJwAAWKb6qCamFQOcUpgEYKBIH2FzUKIojCYFXJXAxTFMD+4XSdFjaAZAsHxXGeJJfEKVpRlRhZXKuWiP5QA)

Can somebody please shed light on what's going on here?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, as per [ms/TS#30708](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30708). Something about nested conditional array types causes the false branch to be taken prematurely. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If you replace the final branch `T | U` in the definition of `And` with just `true`, it works as expected, which makes sense with @jcalz explanation

Comment: @jcalz: Yes, it does address the question. Would also love to see your answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @overwriter please note that my suggestion works only as a coincidence, the fact that the conditional gets to the last branch when it should  postpone its evaluation until it has the argument of `shortcut` is a bug!

Comment: I was already aware. ;) Thank you for the diligence though, much appreciated!

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to be quite the full explanation, since I'm seeing discrepancies as I write up my answer. I'm going to go to sleep and revisit in the morning to see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: Essentially the bug I mentioned above has apparently been fixed, but your problem remains.   I've reduced your example to [this](https://tsplay.dev/wedy1W) and I will probably file a new GitHub issue about it and get back to you when it's triaged. Is that acceptable?

Comment: It's [ms/TS#57650](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57650), btw. Still waiting for official word about it.